# Bookmarklet not working/opening in IE10

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, internet-explorer-10

I created a bookmarklet (tiny javascript function) that works well in ie7,8,9 and Firefox, Chrome, safari but its not working in IE10. Actually not opening in the IE10 when user clicks on the bookmarklet button on the bookmarks bar.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var jsScript=document.createElement('script');
jsScript.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
jsScript.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo base_url()?>bookmarklet');
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jsScript);
var jq=document.createElement('script');jq.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');jq.setAttribute('src', '<?php echo base_url()?>js/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.js');

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);})();"
title="bookmarklet" 
alt="bookmarklet" 
name="bookmarklet" 
class="bookmarklet_bt_dragable" 
style="cursor:move;">bookmarklet</a>
```

The bookmarklet button, by clicking which bookmarklet has to open.

Please someone suggest me how to handle this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You should add the bookmarklet's code. In fact, it seems you haven't been including code in any of your questions so far. This makes it very unlikely you will be getting any answers.

Comment: I have added the bookmarklet opening code. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

In the code snippet I use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
```

to create head object to append my javaScript file to it.

IE10 treat thia unrated due to this line and as a result discard the javascript code at the time of bookmarklet adding.

Please use

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0)
```

instead of

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
```

this line and it will work  well if any one face this problem.

Comment: I'm also having this problem, and this fix is not working for me. What causes this "unrated" message? I can find no documentation anywhere.

Comment: Please upload your javascript bookmarklet code to improve it if it has any problem